# Why is the timezone of Connect/webhook dates not UTC?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

When processing webhook posts, I see the dates are all in my (Eastern US) timezone.  This is reported correctly if I apply the option to include Time Zone Information.

I can work with this, but I have a few questions:

1. why not send in UTC, which is used consistently -- I believe -- throughout the API? (At least, the REST API)
2. Is Time Zone Information working correctly?  I ask because this [report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803210/docusign-gives-incorrect-timezoneoffset-in-webhook-event-data%20issue) says it doesn't support fractional info, such as India's UTC+5.5 correctly.)
3. What Time Zone is used in the webhook posts?  I have changed both my personal preference and my account setting to Katmandu, but I still Eastern.  (Thus, I cannot test #2 myself.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1.) Most datetimes coming back from API are UTC, however SOAP and Connect messages follow a hidden account setting. You will need to ask support to change it. It's called "Time Zone used for Connect and SOAP".

2.) Fractional datetimes should work fine

3.) Webhook and SOAP currently use the same time zone as mentioned above. Your UI preferences (account settings and personal preferences) that you see are aimed at UI users. Since you are an API integrator, they follow a different setting.

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes on hold and 25 explaining this to DocuSign support.  I was ultimately told they don't know how to do this, and that I need to engage professional services.  That can't be right, can it?

Comment: You don't need professional services. Do you have an Account Managers, or are you a web customer (paid for one of the online plans?). AMs can help once you give them that account setting mentioned above. Feel free to ping me directly also.

Comment: We have an AM, but he hasn't helped us thus far.  Consider yourself pinged (pung?)  I'll ask our AM for your contact info.

Comment: Yes!  I received notification yesterday and just had a chance to test it.  The good news is that the API time zone was changed as requested.  The bad news is that this confirms the bug.  The  Connect post I just received contains this:
<TimeZone>Nepal Standard Time</TimeZone>
<TimeZoneOffset>5</TimeZoneOffset>
But the correct timezone for Nepal is GMT+5:45.

Comment: Will track this as a bug. Thanks for your patience getting through this.

Comment: 3.5 years and one pandemic later -- any news on this bug?
Nepal is not actually an important marked for us, but India is.